# Condition to check if value from gridview cell was edited or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know if there's any condition to check if values from cells were edited or not .
I can do it in other way ( with If value == value ) bla bla..but I need to write a lot to compare the values ..and I need another way .

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a custom object or a datatable?

Comment: do you need to do this at client side or check against the db on postback?

Comment: I want to add in griview on update event to check if values were edited , if yes then I will add in a textbox some text else nothing will happen

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a custom object/List bind with an object datasource. You can define a base class,inherit it & mark your objects dirty like

```
public class ObjectBase
{
    private bool _isDirty;
    private bool _isNew = true;
    protected void MarkDirty()
    {
         _isDirty = true;
    }
    protected void MarkAsNew()
    {
         _isNew = true;
    }
    public bool IsDirty
    {
         get { return _isDirty; }
    }
  }
```

Then inside your object class you will inherit this base class like

```
public class myClass:ObjectBase
{ 
    public int Id {get; set;} 
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Whenver you update your object, mark them as dirty in presentation layer, then you check for them being dirty in business layer like, if yes update else return 'no changes to update'

```
    public static bool UpdateItem(Employee myEmployee)
   {
        if(myEmployee.IsDirty)
      {
            return myEmployeeDB.UpdateItem(myEmployee);
      }
   }
```

Comment: heh so much code , I was asking for a simple statment to check if the cell was edited or not

Answer (score 0):

DataGridViewCell does not track changes. If you need to know that Value has changed for one cell only, use CellValueChanged event and do your stuff there. If you need to know which cells have been modified, so you can enumerate them and do what is necessary, try this:

```
HashSet<DataGridViewCell> changedCells = new HashSet<DataGridViewCell>();
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
    if (!changedCells.Contains(dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]))
    {
        changedCells.Add(dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to hook to CellValueChanged event of DataGridView. When you need a list of changed cells, do this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in changedCells)
{
        // Your work here
}
```

This works on UI level only. You will need different approach if your data gets changed by code also.

Comment: hmm , cellvalue changed can't be found what's the library used?

Comment: My bad, I assumed (yet again wrongly) the same functionality between platforms. This is WinForms only, sorry.

Comment: uff , any way of doing this in asp.net?

Comment: You might do the testing in RowUpdating as you have old and new values for cells. Are you monitoring one cell in particular or looking for any change in the row?

Comment: I'm checking particular cell but it takes too long , I mean I need too many conditions to add..it would be better if the program would look if any change was made on witch cell and add a messaje with some values from it

Comment: Where and how you compare values? Can you share your current code?