# Datagridview check for changes and insert records

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datagridview

I have a datagridview loaded from the SQL Server database containing an editable column. I want to check if the user has changed the data in the datagridview and after that i can save the data back to the database, and if the user hasn't changed anything then it won't save the data to the database. I don't want to update the data on the original records, after changes in the datagridview it should insert the data back to the database. Something like master and user templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataGridViewCell does not track changes. If you need to know that Value has changed for one cell only, use CellValueChanged event and do your stuff there. If you need to know which cells have been modified, so you can enumerate them and do what is necessary, try this:

```
HashSet<DataGridViewCell> changedCells = new HashSet<DataGridViewCell>();
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
    if (!changedCells.Contains(dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]))
    {
        changedCells.Add(dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex]);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to hook to CellValueChanged event of DataGridView. When you need a list of changed cells, do this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in changedCells)
  {
     // Your work here
  }
```

This works on UI level only. You will need different approach if your data gets changed by code also.

See [Nikola Markovinović's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9583604/880990) to the question [Condition to check if value from gridview cell was edited or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9582903/880990)

Comment: thanks for your reply but actually what i am looking for is to check for any changes in the gridview before inserting the records. I have the template fields in my gridview for editing but after editing how can i know that user has changed anything.

Comment: Note that you don't have to check whether the HashSet contains a value before inserting, because the HashSet doesn't store duplicates by default. It also will not generate an exception if you try to do so, but will simply ignore the attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `OnRowUpdating="GridViewUpdateEventHandler"` of the asp.net grid.

Comment: The DataGridView is a WinForms control, not the ASP.NET grid control.